# Change a column on a query depending if another value already exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my SQL query

```
SELECT 
    T0.DocDate, T0.DocNum, T0.TrnspCode, T0.[LicTradNum] as 'Cust Type',
    T0.CardName as 'Customer Name',  T2.ItemName as 'Item Description',
    T1.Quantity , T1.LineTotal as 'Total Sales S$',
    (T1.GrssProfit-ISNULL(T1.U_Add_Cost_SGD,0)) as 'Net GP S$',
    CASE when T0.TrnspCode =5 then '0' else 80 end as Delivery 
FROM
    [dbo].[OINV]  T0
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[INV1]  T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry 
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[OITM]  T2 ON T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode 
INNER JOIN 
    OITB T3 ON T2.ItmsGrpCod = T3.ItmsGrpCod 
INNER JOIN 
    OSLP T4 ON T0.SlpCode = T4.SlpCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    OIDC T5 ON T0.Indicator=T5.Code
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    OSHP T6 ON T0.TrnspCode = T6.TrnspCode 
WHERE 
    T0.DocType <> 'S'
    AND T4.SlpName <> '-No Sales Employee-'
    AND T2.ItemName LIKE '%compressed wood%'
    AND T0.[LicTradNum] LIKE '%Enno%'
    AND year(T0.DocDate) = YEAR(getdate()) 
    AND month(T0.DocDate) = MONTH(getdate())
```

The output when I run the above query:

```
DocDate                 DocNum      TrnspCode Cust Type                        Customer Name                                                                                        Item Description                                                                                     Quantity                                Total Sales S$                          Net GP S$                               Delivery
----------------------- ----------- --------- -------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- -----------
2016-10-03 00:00:00.000 30072379    4         Enno                             T & C Manufacturing Company Pte Ltd                                                                  Compressed Wooden Pallet, Model: EGPW-101, Size: 1100mm x 1100mm x 135mm                             200.000000                              2800.000000                             1283.420000                             80
2016-10-03 00:00:00.000 30072379    4         Enno                             T & C Manufacturing Company Pte Ltd                                                                  Compressed Wooden Pallet, Model: EGPW-101, Size: 1100mm x 1100mm x 135mm                             1.000000                                0.000000                                -7.580000                               80
2016-10-04 00:00:00.000 30072416    4         Enno-Ex                          Biomin Singapore Pte Ltd                                                                             Compressed Wood Pallet, Model: EGPW-104, Size: 1220mm x 1020mm x 140mm                               100.000000                              1450.000000                             705.000000                              80
2016-10-04 00:00:00.000 30072435    4         Enno                             GES (Singapore) Pte Ltd                                                                              Compressed Wood Pallet, Model: EGPW-104, Size: 1220mm x 1020mm x 140mm                               50.000000                               725.000000                              352.500000                              80
2016-10-05 00:00:00.000 30072413    4         Enno                             Markem-Imaje                                                                                         Compressed Wooden Pallet, Model: EGPW-101, Size: 1100mm x 1100mm x 135mm                             50.000000                               700.000000                              320.850000                              80
2016-10-06 00:00:00.000 30072474    4         Enno                             Faci Asia Pacific Pte Ltd                                                                            Compressed Wooden Pallet, Model: EGPW-101, Size: 1100mm x 1100mm x 135mm                             50.000000                               775.000000                              389.090000                              80
```

The last column, delivery, should also depend on that row DocNum being the first time it has appeared on the query. When that DocNum has appeared on a previous row then we will return a 0, otherwise we will calculate the return value depending of TrnspCode as the query already does.

You can see it in this example for DocNum 30072379, the first time it appears it has to return 80, while on the second apparition it should return 0 :

```
DocDate                 DocNum      TrnspCode Cust Type                        Customer Name                                                                                        Item Description                                                                                     Quantity                                Total Sales S$                          Net GP S$                               Delivery
----------------------- ----------- --------- -------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- -----------
2016-10-03 00:00:00.000 30072379    4         Enno                             T & C Manufacturing Company Pte Ltd                                                                  Compressed Wooden Pallet, Model: EGPW-101, Size: 1100mm x 1100mm x 135mm                             200.000000                              2800.000000                             1283.420000                             80
2016-10-03 00:00:00.000 30072379    4         Enno                             T & C Manufacturing Company Pte Ltd                                                                  Compressed Wooden Pallet, Model: EGPW-101, Size: 1100mm x 1100mm x 135mm                             1.000000                                0.000000                                -7.580000                               0
2016-10-04 00:00:00.000 30072416    4         Enno-Ex                          Biomin Singapore Pte Ltd                                                                             Compressed Wood Pallet, Model: EGPW-104, Size: 1220mm x 1020mm x 140mm                               100.000000                              1450.000000                             705.000000                              80
2016-10-04 00:00:00.000 30072435    4         Enno                             GES (Singapore) Pte Ltd                                                                              Compressed Wood Pallet, Model: EGPW-104, Size: 1220mm x 1020mm x 140mm                               50.000000                               725.000000                              352.500000                              80
2016-10-05 00:00:00.000 30072413    4         Enno                             Markem-Imaje                                                                                         Compressed Wooden Pallet, Model: EGPW-101, Size: 1100mm x 1100mm x 135mm                             50.000000                               700.000000                              320.850000                              80
2016-10-06 00:00:00.000 30072474    4         Enno                             Faci Asia Pacific Pte Ltd                                                                            Compressed Wooden Pallet, Model: EGPW-101, Size: 1100mm x 1100mm x 135mm                             50.000000                               775.000000                              389.090000                              80
```

please help me to amend my query

Comment: Can you explain with more detail what do you mean with : "i need the output in last delivery column based on unique docnum it should calculate only one time ". I don't really understand how do you need to calculate that column.

Comment: I think what he means: If the DocNum already exists, the last column(Delivery) should be 0

Comment: The only DocNum that I can see on that Query is on the OINV (T0) TABLE, so it will always exist.

Comment: so in that case 30072379 should be 80 second line should be 0 30072416 should be 80

Comment: need the query like that

Comment: Yes, I understand that in that case you need to return a 0. What I don't really understand is what that case really is. You should expand your explanation of this condition.

Comment: @MarcGuillot the DocNum 30072379 exists twice. In that case, he wants the first entry in Delivery to be "80" and for all others with DocNum 30072379 Delivery should be "0"

Comment: yes with that condtion according docnum

Comment: @jogoe your are correct

Comment: For future reference: [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/). It helps people out if they have the sample data setup, so they can fiddle with it locally in SSMS or in [RexTester](http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler) or [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) or similar online tools like that.

Comment: @jogoe Thanks, now I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried my best on this, might work:

```
SELECT T0.DocDate, T0.DocNum, T0.TrnspCode, T0.[LicTradNum] as 'Cust Type',
       T0.CardName as 'Customer Name',  T2.ItemName as 'Item Description',
       T1.Quantity , T1.LineTotal as 'Total Sales S$',
       (T1.GrssProfit-ISNULL(T1.U_Add_Cost_SGD,0)) as 'Net GP S$',
       CASE when T0.TrnspCode =5 then '0' 
            when COALESCE(T0.DocNum) = T0.DocNum then '80'
            when 
            (
            SELECT count(T0.DocNum) FROM [dbo].[OINV] T0 
            GROUP BY T0.DocNum
            )>1 then '0' 
            else 80 end as Delivery 
FROM [dbo].[OINV]  T0
INNER JOIN [dbo].[INV1]  T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[OITM]  T2 ON T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode 
INNER JOIN OITB T3 ON T2.ItmsGrpCod = T3.ItmsGrpCod 
INNER JOIN OSLP T4 ON T0.SlpCode = T4.SlpCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN OIDC T5 ON T0.Indicator=T5.Code
LEFT OUTER JOIN OSHP T6 ON T0.TrnspCode = T6.TrnspCode 
WHERE T0.DocType <> 'S'
  AND T4.SlpName <> '-No Sales Employee-'
  AND T2.ItemName Like '%compressed wood%'
  and T0.[LicTradNum] like '%Enno%'
  and year(T0.DocDate) =YEAR(getdate()) and month(T0.DocDate) = MONTH(getdate())
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near '>'.

Comment: COALESCE(T0.DocNum) - First Error refer to this line

Comment: yes using COALESE there isnt right, sorry. Its really hard for me to solve this because i cant really test out anything.

Comment: My question is simple if the two line with same document number first line I need to do one calculation and second should not

Comment: i know what you want, i just dont know how to implement it - if its so easy maybe you can find a solution on your own

Answer (score 0):

This is your query with a subquery that checks if that DocNum has already appeared :

```
SELECT T0.DocDate, T0.DocNum, T0.TrnspCode, T0.[LicTradNum] as 'Cust Type',
       T0.CardName as 'Customer Name',  T2.ItemName as 'Item Description',
       T1.Quantity , T1.LineTotal as 'Total Sales S$',
       (T1.GrssProfit-ISNULL(T1.U_Add_Cost_SGD,0)) as 'Net GP S$',
       CASE when T0.TrnspCode =5 or exists (select * from OINV T7 where T7.DocNum = T0.DocNum and T7.DocDate < T0.DocDate) then '0' 
                 else 80 end as Delivery 
FROM [dbo].[OINV]  T0
INNER JOIN [dbo].[INV1]  T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[OITM]  T2 ON T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode 
INNER JOIN OITB T3 ON T2.ItmsGrpCod = T3.ItmsGrpCod 
INNER JOIN OSLP T4 ON T0.SlpCode = T4.SlpCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN OIDC T5 ON T0.Indicator=T5.Code
LEFT OUTER JOIN OSHP T6 ON T0.TrnspCode = T6.TrnspCode 
WHERE T0.DocType <> 'S'
  AND T4.SlpName <> '-No Sales Employee-'
  AND T2.ItemName Like '%compressed wood%'
  and T0.[LicTradNum] like '%Enno%'
  and year(T0.DocDate) =YEAR(getdate()) and month(T0.DocDate) = MONTH(getdate())
```

Comment: 2016-10-13 00:00:00.000 30072772 4 Enno-Ex KWE - Kintetsu World Express (S) Pte Ltd Compressed Wood Pallet, Model: EGPW-104, Size: 1220mm x 1020mm x 140mm 500.000000 7400.000000 3609.870000 80
2016-10-13 00:00:00.000 30072772 4 Enno-Ex KWE - Kintetsu World Express (S) Pte Ltd Compressed Wooden Pallet, Model: EGPW-101, Size: 1100mm x 1100mm x 135mm 500.000000 6500.000000 2640.850000 80

Comment: still the same you can see above comment

Comment: Yes, I see, let me prepare another query.

Comment: Thnaks please help me

Comment: The check with a subquery has failed because both lines have the same DocDate, so we can't distinguish them to kow which on is the first and which one is the second. I think that using CTE (Common Table Expressions) is the correct way to solve this problem, but I have never used them. I will give it a try and answer back if I get them to work.